# c++11 syntax variadic templates expand with rebind

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, gcc, metaprogramming

Is this a valid c++ syntax?

```
template<typename Var, typename T>
struct rebindVar;

template<typename Var, typename... T>
struct rebindVar<Var, std::tuple<T...> > {
  typedef typename std::tuple< typename T::template rebindVar<Var>::type... > type;
};
```

Working in gcc, doesn't work in vs2013. The error message says:

```
Error   1   error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand   C:\Users\Alexandros\Desktop\project\tnnlib\src\NeuralNetwork\NeuralNetwork\Perceptron\Perceptron.h  55  1   NeuralNetwork_ut
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC's variadic templates implementation is a huge mess, and many slightly more complex expansion patterns don't work. The usual workaround is to extract the complex part into a helper template. Try this:

```
template <typename Var, typename T>
struct rebindOne { typedef typename T::template rebindVar<Var>::type type; };

template<typename Var, typename... T>
struct rebindVar<Var, std::tuple<T...> > {
  typedef typename std::tuple< typename rebindOne<Var, T>::type... > type;
};
```